# Can't connect to local MySql database from the containerized Asp.net Core Application

Tags: mysql, asp.net, docker, dockerfile, containers

I have a simple asp.netcore 3.1 project and I have built the image for the same. This image is running locally on machine and when I have tried to access it is working fine.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["myApp"]
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/myApp"
RUN dotnet build "myApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "myApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myApp.dll"]
```

Now when I'm trying to fetch the data from my local MySql DB and the connection string is:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MysqlDefault": "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;database=myDb;uid=root;pwd=1234;"
  },
```

This is the error it is throwing:
**fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
An error occurred using the connection to database 'myDb' on server '127.0.0.1'.**

Tried most of the approaches but it didn't worked for. Any approach or clue?

Comment: which environment is your Mysql running in docker or local?

Comment: As your application and the database running in different container, you can not connect to localhost, you have to connect to the container name where the database is running in. Localhost is the container where your application is running in

Comment: @DenisMicheal Mysql is running in local

Comment: @Jens I know what are you saying but the db is running locally and how to do that is my question

Comment: What means *locally*?

Comment: means it is running on my local machine and it is not running on any container

Comment: Try to use the external IP of your machine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256111/discussion-between-shubham-and-jens).

Comment: [i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host), use `host.docker.internal`

Comment: @Jens _The host has a changing IP address, or none if you have no network access. We recommend that you connect to the special DNS name `host.docker.internal`._

Comment: @DenisMicheal the link you have shared I have already followed that but it didn't worked for me

Comment: what error did it throw? when you used host.docker.internal instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: Use Docker Compose to build the containers. Check this [link](https://www.yogihosting.com/docker-aspnet-core-sql-server-crud) on Docker Compose with SQL Server.